# How do I use the Impressionist gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the [Impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem.

I want to display a hit counter of one particular page, in that same view.

This is what I did:

1. Install the gem.
2. Run generator.
3. Add column `counter_cache` to the migration.
4. Run `rake db:migrate`.
5. Add `impressionist :actions=>[:show`] to the controller that I want to track impressions from.
6. Add `is_impressionable :counter_cache => true` to the model pertaining to the controller above.
7. Restart server.

I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't the counter_cache number get increased for each impression (and each respective record)?
2. Is there any method I can use in the view to display the hit count, or should I craft my own query?

Comment: Please link to the gem source on github, to ease people helping you with this uncommon gem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to show how much hits:

```
<%= @model_instance.impressionist_count %> views
```

Put this in your view.